# SQL расчет разницы

Tags: sql

Добрый день. Есть следующая таблица:

```
    BAL_DATE     LS_VH    BS_SIGN     LS_NOM  
    20160930     0.25     A            20621
    20160930     1247.7   L            20648
    20161004     0.27     A            20621
    20160930     3254.4   A            20624
    20161004     1987.7   L            20648
    20161004     3254.3   A            20624
```

Пояснения к таблице: LS_NOM - это номер счета, LS_VH - остаток на счету, BAL_DATE - по состоянию на какую дату указаны значения.

Необходимо посчитать как изменился остаток по каждому из счетов по сравнению с предыдущей датой. Примерно так:

```
    BAL_DATE     LS_VH    BS_SIGN     LS_NOM  Difference
    20160930     0.25     A            20621  0.00
    20160930     1247.7   L            20648  0.00
    20161004     0.27     A            20621  0.02
    20160930     3254.4   A            20624  0.00
    20161004     1987.7   L            20648  740.00
    20161004     3254.3   A            20624  -0.01
```

Пытался сделать следующий запрос, но он некорректно работает, так как считает только разницу между строками и не учитывает номер счета.

```
    SELECT  
        [current].BAL_DATE, 
        [current].LS_VH, 
        [current].BS_SIGN, 
        ISNULL([next].LS_VH, 0) - [current].LS_VH AS Difference, 
        [current].LS_NOM
    FROM SQL_LP AS [current] LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SQL_LP AS [next] ON [next].LS_VH = (SELECT MIN(LS_VH) FROM SQL_LP WHERE (LS_VH > [current].LS_VH))
```

Буду благодарен, если подскажете, как можно реализовать подобный запрос (MS SQL Server 2012).
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В SQL Server 2012 есть замечательная оконная функция [LAG()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh231256.aspx) дающая как раз предыдущее значение требуемой колонки.

```
SELECT  
        [current].BAL_DATE, 
        [current].LS_VH, 
        [current].BS_SIGN, 
        lag(LS_VH,1,0) over(partition by LS_NOM order by BAL_DATE) -
         [current].LS_VH AS Difference, 
        [current].LS_NOM
  FROM SQL_LP AS [current]
```